# pygame object moves for a second

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

The 'PlayerRect' in the code appears in the screen, and i can move it, but it only moves for a fraction of a second before returning to the position that it started.  I've used different codes to give it movement, but they all have the same result.  Any suggestions?

```
import pygame,sys,os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init


MOVERATE = 10
WINDOWWIDTH = 500
WINDOWHEIGHT = 500
def terminate():
     pygame.quit()
     sys.exit()

playerImage = pygame.image.load('Test_Block.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()

WHITE = (255,255,255,0)

WindowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.update()


WindowSurface.fill(WHITE)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()



while True:



     moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
     playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWHEIGHT / 2),(WINDOWWIDTH / 2)


     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == QUIT:
               terminate()


          if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                     if event.key == ord('a'):
                         moveRight = False
                         moveLeft = True
                     if event.key == ord('d'):
                         moveLeft = False
                         moveRight = True
                     if event.key == ord('w'):
                         moveDown = False
                         moveUp = True
                     if event.key == ord('s'):
                         moveUp = False
                         moveDown = True

                     if event.type == KEYUP:
                         if event.type == K_ESCAPE:
                             terminate()
                         if event.key == ord('a'):
                              moveLeft = False
                         if event.type == ord('d'):
                              moveRight = False
                         if event.key == ord('w'):
                              moveUp = False
                         if event.key == ord('s'):
                              moveDown = False


     if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
          playerRect.move_ip(-1 * MOVERATE,0)
     if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
          playerRect.move_ip(MOVERATE,0)
     if moveUp and playerRect.top >0:
          playerRect.move_ip(0,-1 * MOVERATE)
     if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
          playerRect.move_ip(0,MOVERATE)

     WindowSurface.blit(playerImage,playerRect)
     pygame.display.update()
     mainClock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that you reset the position of playerRect every time through the loop.  Take the move_* = false line and the playerRect.topleft line and move them to before the while loop:

```
moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWHEIGHT / 2),(WINDOWWIDTH / 2)

while True:

     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == QUIT:
               terminate()
```

If that doesn't fix things, trace the position.  On each loop iteration, print the coordinates of playerRect to a log file.  Also trace the key events.  This will discriminate between a failure in display from a failure in positioning.